# "The request is badly formed" while trying to fetch Azure Management Events via REST API

Tags: api, azure

According to that article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931934.aspx,

I am trying to fetch the list of events doing following:

```
$ curl -X GET -H  "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIP-TI0N-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&\$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2014-12-29T22:00:37Z' and eventTimestamp le '2014-12-29T23:36:37Z' and eventChannels eq 'Admin, Operation'" -v


* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.97.164.182...
* Connected to management.azure.com (23.97.164.182) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: management.azure.com
* Server certificate: Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> GET /subscriptions/SUBSCRIP-TI0N-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2014-12-29T22:00:37Z' and eventTimestamp le '2014-12-29T23:36:37Z' and eventChannels eq 'Admin, Operation' HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: management.azure.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Authorization:Bearer {mytokenthere}
>
```

But the result is:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
* Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 10:06:38 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 311
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

But it seems to be exactly the same request as in msdn example.

I believe it must be something wrong with filter param, when I amend it the response states that filter parameter is invalid:

```
curl -X GET -H  "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIP-TI0N-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01"
<Error xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>The $filter query parameter value is invalid.</Message></Error>
```

I also tried other filter options from the msdn article - the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, so it turns out that I incorrectly called curl and the problem is actually stupid :)

this is the way it works:

```
curl -H  "Accept:application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp%20ge%20%272015-11-29T22:00:37Z%27'
```

so %20 is used instead of spaces, and %27 instead of '

and it works!

Comment: Wow , thanks man! after two days of trying, this solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the date range you're specifying. Please note that **you can only query for last 90 days of data** and you're querying the data for last year:

> eventTimestamp ge **'2014-12-29T22:00:37Z'** and eventTimestamp le
>   **'2014-12-29T23:36:37Z'**

Please try by changing the date/time range. Otherwise your query looks fine.

Comment: it still doesn't work:

`curl -H  "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscribtion}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&\$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2015-11-25T22:00:37Z'"`
returns 
`HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>`

Comment: Hmm...I tried the one you're using above in Google Postman and it worked just fine. I removed slash sign before **$** though. Let me try it in cURL though.

Comment: please try and let me know if it works for you:)
The other thing that can affect this, that I've tried it with token issued for application, probably this is the thing

Comment: Hmmm...really weird! I'm also getting 400 error with cUrl but it works with Google Postman.

Comment: I've just tried it with Google Postman and it works! (Hooray!)

Comment: Ok, it means the using of API is correct, the thing is with curl. I'll write there if I fugure out what is wrong with curl